# In Python, how do you remove the first x bytes of 5 MS Word (.doc) files that you created by scraping website using bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, ms-word, beautifulsoup

Say I have a folder called "Research" that has 5 MS Word files (essay1, essay2, essay3, essay4, essay5). I would like to use Python to remove the first 2000 bytes (characters and spaces) of each file. How might this be done?

Edit for context: I did my first web scraping project using request and BeautifulSoup. I saved the files as "article name" + ".doc." They all seem to open in word but they have 2000 unwanted bytes above each essay (various links and such). I am using MS Word in Windows 10. Python 3.6.

Comment: To be clear, you mean the rendered text seen in the document, not whatever headers and markup may be there also? Which version of Word?

Comment: To see how this is not really possible I suggest you do the following... take a word file (somefile.docx) and rename it to a zip file: (somefile.zip). unzip it, and explore the internal structure. most of the actual text is stored under */word/document.xml* (note if you use 7zip, you don't have to change the name, just right click and select "open archive" under the 7zip context menu)

Comment: Here is more context. I did my first web scraping project. I saved the files as   "article name" + ".doc." They all seem to open in word but they have 2000 unwanted bytes above each essay (various links and such). All the files have these unwanted 2000 bytes. I would like to remove them.

Comment: note that '97 - '03 (.doc) uses a custom binary format instead of xml internally that is (somewhat) readable in notepad++

Comment: if you open with notepad++ is it readable, or is it binary garbage? It sounds a little like these are not actually .doc files, rather you just named plaintext data with a .doc extension

Comment: It is a giant block of text with no line spaces, but readable. It seems to retain all of the HTML from the page I scraped. Before the essay, there are a ton of <div><span> and all that. Then the essay is readable, but it even has the <em> for italics.

Comment: What you have is an .html file then and you should rename it as such. you should look into html parsers to extract the data you want. you should also edit your question to reflect what we've discussed in the comments. this question really doesn't have anything to do with Microsoft, MS Word, or .doc files

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a pretty friendly and well documented html (and xml) parser for python

Comment: I did use bs4. I am confused. When I open in Word there are no html tags.  The essay reads perfectly fine. There are a number of bulleted hyperlinks that precede the essay that I would like to remove. That's all I need to remove. Everything else is fine.

Comment: MS word is capable of rendering html in the same way a browser is. if you right click and "open with" chrome, you'll also see the nicely formatted text. the file itself however (the raw data) is visible when you open it with a plaintext editor such as notepad++, where you'll see all the non-visible commands it took to do this formatting. [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) is a great place to start to learn how html works

Comment: Appreciate your input. I think the question is "How do you use BeautifulSoup to save many online articles as MS Word docs, minus the first x bytes of the articles?" Does this make sense?

Comment: There is no python library to directly interface with MS word. After that, is the "remove the first x bytes" to get rid of the html header tags? or is it like to get rid of an abstract and only keep the rest of the article?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: The MS word files I created look like this: It says "Submit" and then there is a bulleted list of hyperlinks for Twitter, FB, Google+, etc. Then there are bulleted hyperlinks to other parts of the website. Then there are Issues and a bulleted list of hyperlinked tags. Finally, the essay starts and all is well. I just want to get rid of those hyperlinks for the social media, tags, and other parts of the websites. I think "get rid of the html header tags" is right because I just inspected the page and there are a ton of hyperlinks under a head tag and then it goes to the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open ('your file', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(2000,1)
    data=f.read()
with open ('another file', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

This (I think) will read the data from the 2000th bit in the file and write it into a different file.

I should tell you that this will only delete the raw bytes from the file, and not necessarily what is displayed when you open it with a word processor.

Comment: this will indeed blindly trim 2000 bytes from the beginning of the file, but as per the comments, I'm not sure the OP has a terribly clear idea of what needs to be done. The way he talks about it, he wants to extract the plaintext article from a full html page. (much less trivial than simply trimming off some bytes at the beginning of a file)

Comment: Update: I used bs4 to pull the div tag that includes the text of the essay. I saved that as x and did file.write(str(x)). This method saved the essay without all of the extra junk; however, this time the html tags are in there. It seems the only choices are (1) using the content from request.get (which looks great except for all of the hyperlinks that precede the essay) and (2) the file.write(str(x)) option. If there was a way to use requests.get to get the part of the page I want, that would be great. But I guess that is not an option because requests doesn't parse the html.